# How to remove 2FA from launch.stellar.org login

Tags: stellar-website

Need some help. 
I had account in https://launch.stellar.org/#/login in 2014. 
I wanted to log in, but only thing I have is -  username and RECOVERY code for password reset. 
But when I enter these two, it asks for the 2FA code. That I don't have.

How can I get rid of 2FA to reset my password?

Answer (score 1):

Use this link to disable 2FA for the account:

https://launch.stellar.org/#/lost-2fa-device